# Increasing value from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function but it is not working 100% and I am unsure why. Currently I load the invoice template and it shows 0001.

If I add the invoice, it is added to the database and what its meant to do is that if the latest row is not equal to 0001 then make it 0002 and so forth, same if it was 1872 would do next number up from latest invoice in MySQL.

PHP

```
define('INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE','0001');    

// Connect to the database
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);

        // output any connection error
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $query = "SELECT invoice FROM invoices ORDER BY invoice DESC LIMIT 1";

        // mysqli select query
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        // get number of returned results, if 0 action it below
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

        //Invoice length
        $invoice = $row['invoice'];

        if($row_cnt == "0"){
            echo INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE;
        } else {
            // check if the initial invoice ID has already been used and if not start from that value else from the next value
            if($invoice != INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) {
                echo ++$invoice;
            }
        }

        // Frees the memory associated with a result
        $result->free();

        // close connection 
        $mysqli->close();
```

Updated like this:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

        /* fetch object array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            $invoice = $row['invoice'];
        }

        if($row_cnt == "0"){
            echo INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE;
        } else {
            // check if the initial invoice ID has already been used and if not start from that value else from the next value
            if($invoice != INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) {
                echo ++$invoice;
            }
        }

        // Frees the memory associated with a result
        $result->free();

        // close connection 
        $mysqli->close();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? What is it not doing that it's supposed to?

Comment: Its returning the value as 1 and not 0002

Comment: is it that it's not keeping the leading zeros or that the number is wrong?

Comment: set the field as a varchar

Comment: field is set to varchar, its storing as 0001 - 0001 now exists but when i go to invoice template it shows as 1 and should be 0002 as 0001 exists

Comment: Did not seem to do the trick.... am i doing the increase of number wrong as well as should be not 1 but 2 regardless (separate from the 000 missing which i need a fix for as well) also the initial invoice number can be anything that someone sets like 87892 etc..

Comment: its not outputting the leading zeros which is one issue, and also its not increasing the number to the next one ++ part.

Comment: where you define `INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE` is this the correct number? It has one more zero than what you've said you're checking for.

Comment: yea it is correct sorry i just placed it in there as its in config file but it is correct.

Comment: You are only getting count of row and not really fetching the row. so ``$invoice = $row['invoice'];`` will be null .  in your code where $row is set ??

Comment: I think that named `auto-increment` field!

Comment: $row_cnt = $result->num_rows; it is counted there and $row - i just updated with some new code but same result...

Comment: So $invoice is returning 1 and not whole invoice number and not increasing still with that while() i added... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right of doing it would be to convert the string into an integer. and then convert it back with leading 0's.
like the following example:

```
$num = '0001'; // string('0001')
$invoiceNumber = intval($num) + 1; // integer(2)
$invoice = str_pad($invoiceNumber, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // string('0002')
```

so you should change it in your code to:

```
else if($invoice != INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) {
    $num = intval($invoice) + 1;
    $invoice = str_pad($num, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $invoice;
}
```

although you should save the data as integer and just present it with leading zeros.

Comment: Problem is that is what i set 0001 the user might define a starting invoice of 6723 for example.... so really would be good if it was possible just to get the latest values from the row and increase it by 1 whatever the value.

Comment: that's not a problem.. it should work even then.. although I suggest to save the data as Integer instead of string. and just present it with leading 0's. use `Str_pad` to do so.

Comment: whats the 4? invoice number length? if so would it not cause a issue if an invoice is 24378943 it can be any length - thanks for your help btw

Comment: it's padding up to this value.. for ex if you pass '1' it will pad it up to 4 characters meanining '0001' and if your entering '10' it will pad it to '0010'. '9999' will remain the same. http://php.net/str_pad

Comment: Its showing 0001 now but that is in the database already so should not be 0002? also so would i need to count the amount of numbers and set the pad maybe?

Comment: you can test the first example in http://phpfiddle.org/ . it works. so you should check your DB.. print  the $invoice after the query to make sure you get anything at all..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77198/discussion-between-dan-revah-and-james).

Comment: so, what was the complete solution here? is that it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to doing Dan Revah suggested, you should correct your logic of the if statement.

```
if($invoice != INVOICE_INITIAL_VALUE) {
```

In the above line, you are checking if $invoice is not equal to 1, only then you are adding 1 to it.

So, when $invoice is equal to 1, you are not adding 1. That's one of the reasons why you are getting 001.